# What is the difference between checkout double dash and hard reset

Tags: git, github

I was trying to delete changes from the local repository. I thought that `git reset --hard HEAD` is responsible for that, but it didn't work. Only `git checkout -- .` helped. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git checkout -- .` tells Git to reach into the current index contents and, for each file in the index, copy that version of that file into the work-tree as long as that file lives at or below the current directory.  (If you're at the top of the repository, this is every file in the index.)

`git reset --hard HEAD` tells Git to reach into the current (`HEAD`) *commit*, copy every file from that commit to the index, and as it goes from commit-to-index, also copy the file to the work-tree.<sup>1</sup>  In many, perhaps even most, cases, this will do the same thing.  In some cases, it won't: it depends on how closely the current index contents match the `HEAD` commit contents.

Let's take an example.  Suppose, for instance, that you began by checking out the tip commit of some branch named `branch`:

```
$ git clone -b branch ssh://git@github.com/path/to/some/repo.git
[the usual clone output happens here]
$ cd repo
```

Then you modified a file (that already exists), *and* ran `git add` on the result:

```
$ echo all-new-contents > README.md
$ git add README.md
```

Then you modified a second file (that also already exists), but *did not* run `git add` on the result:

```
$ echo also all new > COPYING
```

The status at this point is that `README.md` is modified and the new version is in the index, and `file.txt` is modified but the changes are *not* in the index:

```
$ git status --short
 M COPYING
M  README.md
```

Note the positions of the two `M`s.

Using `git checkout -- .`, we'll copy from the index to the work-tree.  This will undo the change we made to `COPYING` since the index version matches the `HEAD` version, but it won't undo the change we made to `README.md` since the index version matches the work-tree version:

```
$ git checkout -- .
$ git status --short
M  README.md
```

If we now use `git reset --hard HEAD`, that copies `README.md` from the commit to the index (so that the index now matches `HEAD` again) and in the process copies the file into normal, edit-able form in the work-tree (so that the work-tree matches the index again):

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD
HEAD is now at 36438dc19 Git 2.16-rc1
$ git status -s
$
```

Note that this is the opposite of the effect you described: `git reset --hard` made things match the commit (as one would expect) while `git checkout -- .` did not (as one should also expect, now that one knows everything there is to know about Git's index<sup>2</sup>).

---

<sup>1</sup>There's a first step that `git reset` performed *before* the index-resetting step, but since the argument was `HEAD`, that first step had no effect, so I omitted it from this description.

<sup>2</sup>Well, at least, one should now be aware that one cannot ignore the *presence* of the index. :-)  Seriously, there is a lot to know here, and you can often ignore *some* of it, but it's critical to remember that not only does the index exist, but you *must* be *aware* of it to use Git.

Answer (score 0):

To say exactly why/how the two commands would apply differently to your changes, we would need more information.  (Every question I've ever seen that said "I thought this would work but it didn't" would be vastly improved by showing relevant inputs and outputs.  In this case, what did `git status` show before and after each command?)

But ok, how do the commands differ?

When you say `git reset --hard HEAD` you're telling git you want to move the currently checked-out branch to the currently checked-out commit (which does nothing), and that you then want to update the index and working tree to reflect that commit (discarding any more recent changes to tracked files).  While new untracked files are not changed, any other change should be cleared - and when I test this, that's what happens.

When you say `git checkout -- .` you are saying that the working tree should be updated by copying every file under `.` (or subdirectories of `.` recursively) from the index.  This will undo unstaged changes to all tracked files, but still won't touch untracked files.  If anything this undoes *fewer* changes than the `reset` command you specified, because it does not update the index from the commit history.  Again my tests agree with this documented behavior.

So as I said, without more information I can't speculate as to why your observations would differ. But that's the difference between the commands.